# How to override OLE DB Timeout Settings programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, dynamics-crm-2013

We’re running into issues updating a SystemUser record’s names because CRM then tries to update all connection records where the SystemUserId is in either Record1Id or Record2Id (to update the “Record1IdName” and “Record2IdName” attributes respectively) and errors out with a SQL Server Timeout Error. We are talking about a few million ConnectionBase records here

I understand that we can increase the OLE DB Timeout on the server but is there a way to do this programmatically in C# code without making changes to the registry of the app/async servers?

Alternatively, is there a way to stop CRM from making these updates?

Comment: you are updating the DB directly or updating via the WS?  Crm will only automatically update things if you update via the WebService.  What are you not tell us?

Comment: then how is CRM updating after the fact unless there is a trigger...

Comment: the timeout you are referring to is a `CommandTimeout` and it should be a property of the Command object

Comment: showing code will make this easier.

Comment: @TMcKeown it's From the UI! Service layer update

Answer (score 1):

This is a Command timeout issue not a connection timeout problem, the default for the command to execute and complete is 30 seconds.

The `OleDbCommand` class has a `CommandTimeout` property that can be set programmatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Why aren't you using the SqlClient native ADO.NET classes?

To answer your question as to why Crm needs to update `Record1IdName` and `Record2IdName` that is to allow your views to display the name of the associated record without having to join.  That is why the updates need to go thru the WS, if you aren't going to update via the WS then you need to know what the consequences are, I would ALWAYS update via the WS for changes to the `Owner` of the record etc or any column that kicks off any workflow.

Comment: what does that mean?  You asked if you can programatically set the command timeout, yes you can.  Are you saying it's not your code?  What does it's from the UI mean?  Does that mean it's from the Dynamics?